# Pass data from locationmanager(..didrangbeacons) to collectionview(...cellforitemat)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, cllocationmanager

I have to update collectionview every time that `locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion)` do a cycle, so i thought to pass `beacons` variables from it to collectionview, how con i do it without using global variables.
Here's the code:

```
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    if !beacons.isEmpty {
        //do things
    }
    else{
        //do other things
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! buttonBeaconsView

    //i want to use beacons data here


    //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.8)
    //cell.createButton()
    //cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return cell
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is location manager in a separate class or in the same view controller ?

Comment: same viewController

Comment: If same view controller you could create a property in the view controller and set it. However it is cleaner to keep it in different classes and follow Duncan's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your view controller serve as the delegate of the location manager. The call to `locationManager(_:didRangeBeacons:in:)` will be made to your view controller. It can then update an **INSTANCE** variable (not a global variable) to hold the new list of beacon information and tell the collection view to update it's contents.

Comment: ok i solved, thank you! i have another little question: in collection view once i have beacons[i] data i want to take only the i-element from beacons[i], how can i do it? should i use indexPath.row to take the single element from beacons[i]?

Comment: Solved using indexPath.row